# Eccentricity of the conic $x^{2}-4xy-2y^{2}+10x+4y=0$?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

**Q:**

> How do I find the eccentricity of the conic $x^{2}-4xy-2y^{2}+10x+4y=0$?

**Doubt:**

How do I solve this, because it is not like the normal hyperbola but also not like the $xy=c^2$ type.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  MathJax commands aren't effective unless they're surrounded by `$` signs.

Comment: The answer is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form).

Comment: $$(x+1)^2-4(x+1)(y-2)-2(y-2)^2=1$$

$$2(x')^2-3(y')^2=1$$

$$e=\sqrt{\frac53}$$

Comment: You rotate the axes to get to the second line. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Conversion_to_canonical_form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do I find the eccentricity of the conic
\begin{align} x^2-4xy-2y^2+10x+4y&=0 \tag{1}\label{1} \end{align}

[A general equation is of the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form)

\begin{align} 
Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F&=0
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

represents a hyperbola, if the its discriminant $\Delta=B^2-4AC>0$.
In case of \eqref{1} we have

\begin{align} 
A&=1
,\quad 
B=-4
,\quad 
C=-2
,\quad 
D=10
,\quad 
E=4
,\quad 
\text{and }\quad F=0
,
\end{align}
hence

\begin{align} 
\Delta&=(-4)^2-4\cdot1\cdot(-2)
=24>0
,
\end{align}
so, the equation \eqref{1} indeed represents a hyperbola
which the eccentricity is given by

\begin{align} 
e&=
\sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}}{\eta(A+C)+\sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}}}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}
where $\eta=1$
if the determinant of the matrix
\begin{align} 
M&=
\begin{bmatrix}
A         & B/2 & D/2 \\
B/2 & C         & E/2 \\
D/2 & E/2 & F  
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}
is negative,
and $\eta=-1$
if the $\det(M)>0$.

For \eqref{1} we have

\begin{align} 
M&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\phantom{-}1 & -2 & 5 \\
-2 & -2 & 2 \\
\phantom{-}5 &  \phantom{-}2 & 0  
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\det{M}&=6>0
,
\end{align}
hence $\eta=-1$ and

\begin{align} 
e&=\sqrt{\tfrac53}
\approx 1.29
.
\end{align}